# Does this photo depict the Sabra and Shatila massacre?

Tags: history, war

The wikipedia entry about [The Sabra and Shatila massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabra_and_Shatila_massacre) contains an assertion with this [dead link](http://www.archive.worldpressphoto.org/search/layout/result/indeling/detailwpp/form/wpp/q/ishoofdafbeelding/true/trefwoord/year/1982):

> [The Sabra and Shatila massacre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9EYM.jpg) (warning: offensive)
>
> Bodies of victims of the massacre in the Sabra and the Shatila refugee camp

But [this](http://inspiringindia28.blogspot.com/) blog post says it's from Gujarat communal riots (1969).

> [Gujarat communal riots (1969)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9EYM.jpg) (warning: offensive)

Does this photo depict the Sabra and Shatila massacre or Gujarat communal riots (1969)?

Comment: Mohammed, please stay away from arguments in comments. Also: do not post offensive images without a warning. It's a common courtesy to our readers.

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.

Comment: @Sklivvz Thanks for the polite response. If you discussed politely before deleting the question, none of this would have happened. And " do not post offensive images without a warning." I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Mohammed: that was my first comment. I'm assuming you meant the other people involved, true. Everyone should stay civil, but please don't escalate if you feel insulted.

Comment: The tags are misleading- this event took place during a war where Israel was involved, but has nothing to do with Israel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link on Wikipedia is dead but the description is enough to find information about the photograph: **"1982, Robin Moyer, World Press Photo of the Year, World Press Photo of the Year"**

A quick search with these terms led to [the up to date page about this photo on worldpressphoto.org](http://www.worldpressphoto.org/collection/photo/1983/world-press-photo-year/robin-moyer).
The photo also appears on [Robin Moyer's website](http://www.robinmoyer.com/gallery.html?folio=Portfolio&gallery=Lebanon%201982#/9), with the label **Sabra - Shatilla Beirut 1982 For Time Magazine**. It seems an account is required to view the content of the article, but the cover is available to all, [on the Time website](http://content.time.com/time/covers/0,16641,19820927,00.html).

Comment: The cynic/skeptic in me is tempted to point out that we only have the word of the photographer that they are images of what he claims they are, and not images from 1969 he appropriated, as opposed to vice versa. A more thorough answer would analyze the writing on the wall (seems Arabic?) and may be if possible make/model of the car.